# didEndEditingRowAt not called with custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview (SettingsViewController) which I use as a user info view where user info is displayed (name, email, phone #, etc). This is similar to the standard iOS contact page.

Each cell has a textfield which is stretched accross the size of the cell, so that once in "edit" mode the user can update his/her info.

I also have a custom Cell (SettingsCell) which is where i setup the cell with the textfield etc.

SettingsViewController (excluded a lot of tabelview setup code):

```
class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController{

    let cellId = "cellId"

    var apiController: APIController?

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var email: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .mainWhite()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.register(SettingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        setupNavigation()

    }

    fileprivate func setupNavigation() {
        editButtonItem.action = #selector(showEditing)
        editButtonItem.title = "Edit"
        editButtonItem.tintColor = .mainWhite()
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    }


    @objc func showEditing(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        if(self.tableView.isEditing == false)
        {
            self.tableView.isEditing = true
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Save"
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        else
        {
            self.tableView.isEditing = false
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell

        if self.tableView.isEditing == true {
            cell.textField.isEnabled = true

            if indexPath.section == 2 {
                cell.textField.keyboardType = .phonePad
            }
        } else {
            cell.textField.isEnabled = false
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        filloutUserInfo(indexPath: indexPath, cell: cell)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    //THIS NEVER GETTING EXECUTED
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
        print("editing done for row \(indexPath?.item)")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
        return .none
    }

}
```

Settings Cell:

```
class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.isEnabled = false
        return tf
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        addSubview(textField)
        textField.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)

        textField.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

The problem I've now encountered is that after I have gone into edit mode, and changed the text of a given cell, the tableview doesn't actually recognize this. The didEndEditingRowAt never gets called and that print statement is never displayed. I am suspecting that is has something to do with the textfield not being connected to the tableviewcontroller in any way, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I need to be able to know when a user has finished editing in order to display an alert for improper formatting and disabling the save button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a callback to listen the `textField` endEditing event from `SettingsCell` to your `ViewController`.

To achieve this, here is the updated `SettingsCell`

```
class SettingsCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField()
        tf.isEnabled = false
        tf.addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
        return tf
    }()

    public var onEndEditing: ((String?) -> Void)?

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        textField.removeFromSuperview()
        addSubview(textField)
        textField.delegate = self

        textField.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 8, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 8, width: 0, height: 0)
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.onEndEditing?(textField.text)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Now update `cellForRowAt` to listen the endEditing event as below,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SettingsCell

    if self.tableView.isEditing == true {
        cell.textField.isEnabled = true
        cell.onEndEditing = { text in 
            print("Cell Editing finished with text: \(text)")
         }
        if indexPath.section == 2 {
            cell.textField.keyboardType = .phonePad
        }
    } else {
        cell.textField.isEnabled = false
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    filloutUserInfo(indexPath: indexPath, cell: cell)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This is really great thanks. The only issue is that it actually "ends" when only one character is added/removed. so isn't actually changing when the user ends typing.

Comment: think you just need to remove textField.removeFromSuperview() from the ayout subviews and add to the end of textFieldDidEndEditing method

Comment: Try removing textfield.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: no if I remove textfield.resignFirstResponder() the action is the same.

Comment: The way I fixed it was to do the following: move resignFirstResponder() and removeFromSuperview() out to the SettingsViewController class inside of the part where we call cell.onEndEditing. This ensures all values are updated when user switches between textfields. if let text = text {
                    self.setNewUserInfo(indexpath: indexPath, info: text)
                    cell.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                    cell.textField.removeFromSuperview()
                }